# how to publish tf in gazebo simulation with depth camera for octomap_server

Tags: ros, gazebo, octomap, ros-kinetic, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using gazebo simulation for drone. I mounted a depth camera on the drone in gazebo. It can publish its odom and pointcloud2 correctly. I would like to use octomap_mapping.launch to get the octree for planning usage, and I change frame_id to /odom, cloud_in to pointcloud2. However, there is nothing when I check with Rviz.

**I think the reason is because my gazebo simulation does not publish a tf, but I am not sure how to do that.** Can anyone tell me what tf should I publish and how to do that?

```
<plugin name='camera_plugin' filename='libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so'>
        <baseline>0.2</baseline>
        <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>camera_ir</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>/camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>/camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
        <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>/camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>/camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.3</pointCloudCutoff>
        <pointCloudCutoffMax>20</pointCloudCutoffMax>
        <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
        <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
        <Cx>0</Cx>
        <Cy>0</Cy>
        <focalLength>0</focalLength>
        <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      </plugin>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343301/how-to-publish-tf-in-gazebo-simulation-with-depth-camera-for-octomap_server/) by [zhefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50329/zhefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I dont know how you are attaching your depth cam to drone, but I assume you are doing it with URDF, in that URDF you should define parent link  of camera_link correctly. If you do attach the depth cam to correct link on the drone , then tf tree should be complete, did you chechk that your tf tree is well connected ?

let us see what your tf tree looks like with;

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

a pdf file will be created in the same directory that you executed above command

Edit;

attaching sensors directly into world file of gazebo is not recommended. The sensors should be attached to body of file(URDF) of robot(drone in this case), and then the this URDF file should be spawned into gazebo.

for instance I can attach a depth camera to base_link of robot as follow;

```
<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="camera_link" />
    <origin rpy="0 1.57 0" xyz="0.6 -0.9 1.6" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
</joint>

<link name="camera_link">

</link>


    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
          <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
            <pose>0.0085 0.0105 0.0197 0 0 0</pose>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <camera>
              <horizontal_fov>1.01229</horizontal_fov>
              <image>
                <width>1024</width>
                <height>1024</height>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
              </image>
              <clip>
                <near>0.2</near>
                <far>1.5</far>
              </clip>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
              <baseline>0.2</baseline>
              <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
              <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
                will control the frame rate. -->
              <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
              <cameraName>camera_ir</cameraName>
              <imageTopicName>/camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
              <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
              <depthImageTopicName>/camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
              <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>/camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
              <pointCloudTopicName>/camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
              <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
              <pointCloudCutoff>0.2</pointCloudCutoff>
              <pointCloudCutoffMax>1.5</pointCloudCutoffMax>
              <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
              <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
              <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
              <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
              <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
              <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
              <Cx>0</Cx>
              <Cy>0</Cy>
              <focalLength>0</focalLength>
              <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
            </plugin>
          </sensor>
    </gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2020-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50329/zhefan/) on 2020-02-04**:
I have actually check that pdf file. It simply says NO tf. And I've checked the rostopic, there is no /tf topic.
Someone else gave me the .world file saying the depth camera is mounted inside.
Below is the depth camera I found in the .world file:

```
<sensor name='camera2' type='depth'>
          <camera name='__default__'>
            <horizontal_fov>1.8</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.02</near>
              <far>100</far>
            </clip>
            <noise>
              <type>gaussian</type>
              <mean>0</mean>
              <stddev>0.005</stddev>
            </noise>
          </camera>
```

Also added extra info in the question.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-04**:
are you calling `joint_state_publisher` and `robot_state_publisher` somewhere in your launch file ? , It is hard to tell what is going on without seeing code. Do you have any github repo of this project

**Comment by [zhefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50329/zhefan/) on 2020-02-04**:
Sure, I have added to my github repo. https://github.com/Zhefan-Xu/drone
Basically, the following file is what I want to use:
launch/tunnel_drone.launch
worlds/tunnel_1.world

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-04**:
why you commented out spawn_drone node ?, my system is 18.04 and gazebo 9 so i couldn't try the package

**Comment by [zhefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50329/zhefan/) on 2020-02-04**:
Because somehow that node causes error.

Anyway, If I mounted the sensor correctly (as you mentioned, attach it to the base_link of robot), the TF would also be published right?

Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-05**:
yes, once the robot body and its sensors are are defined  correctly in URDF, `joint_state_publisher` and
`robot_state_publisher` will publish the transforms between all existing links which is simply /tf topic